# Pop up window with dynamic list view

Tags: android, popupwindow

I have an Array list of xml files (xmlList) created like that :

```
private static ArrayList<File> xmlList = new ArrayList<File>();
public static ArrayList<File> XMLContact(File directory, File contactDirectory,
ArrayList<Contact> myContactList) {
if (!(directory.exists())) {
directory.mkdirs();}
if (!(contactDirectory.exists())) {
contactDirectory.mkdirs();
}
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yyyy hh-mm-ss");
String FileName = df.format(c.getTime());
File newxmlfile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+ "/newfile/contactfile/"+FileName+"xml");  
xmlList.add(newxmlfile);
```

And then want to show the elements of this list in a pop up window (after clicking in a button: button contact ) .So I wrote this code

```
private void onClickButtonContact(View view) {
Button myButton = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonContact);
myButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
 @Override
 public void onClick(View v) {
     xmlList = CreateContactXML.getXmlList();
     AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
     for (int i =1 ; i< xmlList.size(); i++)  
     {Log.e (  null, xmlList.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
     final String path ;
     path  = xmlList.get(i).getName();
     builder.setTitle("Backup Date"); 
     builder.setItems(i, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Restore done for ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                                
     }
     });
     AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
     alert.show();
}
}
}
});
}
```

The List is created and i can loggout its elements. But  the problem is that the pop window contains only the title .

Answer (score 1):

Show List in Alert as:

```
  ArrayList<String> arrfile_path=new ArrayList<String>(); 
    for (int i =1 ; i< xmlList.size(); i++)
    arrfile_path.add(xmlList.get(i).getAbsolutePath());
    builder.setTitle("Backup Date");
    builder.setItems(arrfile_path, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

      // your code here
    });
```

because currently you are passing only index(i) to `builder.setItems`

Comment: I had this error:    
The method setItems(int, DialogInterface.OnClickListener) in the type AlertDialog.Builder is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<String>, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){})